# Winter 21 release ''Disabled Ref ID and New Threading Behavior for Email-To-Case"

Tags: emailmessage, email2case, critical-update

When I enabled this critical update on my sandbox, I am facing some issues even though I have disabled it.

The issues are as follows:

1.The auto-response email is missing under the case feed.

2.Whenever the customer sends an email to this automated email, a new case is creating instead of assigning it under the original case feed.

Please let me know how to fix these issues.

Comment: Your first sentence is not clear. Are these issues you faced with the update enabled or are you trying to disable the update after enabling it and still seeing the same issue?

Comment: Though I have disabled the update, I am still facing these issue which were not there before enabling

Comment: Do outbound emails now have refIds since you disabled the update? Did you make any changes when it was enabled to support the new update that you might need to undo now that it's disabled again? It's possible you may need to reach out to support if you find that it's not actually disabled (no ref Ids still).